# JAX RS injected URIInfo returning localhost for REST requests in reverse proxy

Tags: jax-rs, haproxy

I have a set of IBM Websphere Liberty profiles servers inside a HAProxy reverse proxy. Everything works ok but HAProxy is doing something on requests so I can't get the correct URL in the requests using `uriInfo.getBaseUri()` or `uriInfo.getRequestUriBuilder().build("whatever path")`... they both return localhost:9080 as host and port, so I can't build correct URLs pointing to the service. (The request is a standard http://api.MYHOST.com/v1/... REST request )

Of course, I get a `uriInfo` object using `@Context` in the method so it gets the request information.

Front end configuration:

```
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
  # Add CORS headers when Origin header is present
  capture request header origin len 128
  http-response add-header Access-Control-Allow-Origin %[capture.req.hdr(0)] if { capture.req.hdr(0) -m found }
  rspadd Access-Control-Allow-Methods:\ GET,\ HEAD,\ OPTIONS,\ POST,\ PUT  if { capture.req.hdr(0) -m found }
  rspadd Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:\ true  if { capture.req.hdr(0) -m found }
  rspadd Access-Control-Allow-Headers:\ Origin,\ X-Requested-With,\ Content-Type,\ Accept  if { capture.req.hdr(0) -m found }
```

And Back-end configuration is:

```
  option forwardfor
  http-request set-header Host api.MYHOST.com
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[dst]
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
```

Any ideas on how to get the real request?

Comment: You don't have to use the UrlInfo. You can use a [UriBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) directly.

Comment: Thanks but can you be more specific or give an example? Can I get the UriBuilder using @Context?

Comment: No just use one of the many static methods. The UriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder returns a UriBuilder that is prefilled with the base uri. But you can create the builder manually. `UriBuilder.fromUri(...)`. You can also use `.path(Resource.Class).path(Method)`. to build the uri from the resource/methods instead of using static strings. Just play with all the methods. Look at the link above to see all the methods.

Comment: For example I do UriBuilder.fromUri(URI.create("/")).build()) and get "/", no hostname or port anywhere. All other methods return "localhost" as hostname whatever hostname I use in the real request in Postman. For some reason, my app server (Liberty profile) is converting all requests to localhost and I can't find any way to get the original host used in the original REST request.

Comment: If I do UriBuilder.fromUri(uriInfo.getBaseUri()).build()) (@Context uriInfo) I get localhost in the host, while I am using another host name to access the REST request.

Comment: Can you somehow get access to the real hostname (outside of using anything related to Jersey), maybe from some configuration file. If you can, then what you can do is change the host before it reaches any resource. You can do that in a [prematching filter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9336)

Comment: request.getServerName() is the only thing returning the host name used in the sequest, so I will use it to build the URL...

Comment: Also check out the link for the filter. This might be something you want to do  globally using `context.setRequestUri`. If you do this, you will be able to use the UriInfo like normal.

Comment: I got a solution using UriBuilder and URIBuilder (HttpClient utils). Will add an answer...

Answer (score 3):

The only way I managed to get correct host used in the request is injecting in the method parameters the HttpServletRequest object.
I also inject the UriInfo, which has all valid information except the host name:

```
@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @Context HttpServletRequest request
```

After that I use URIBuilder (not UriBuilder) from Apache HttpClient utils to change the Host to the correct one as jax-rs UriBuilder in immutable:

```
new URIBuilder(uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path("/MyPath").queryParam("MyParameter",myParameterValue)).build()).setHost(request.getServerName()).toString()
```

I also had to include setPort() and setScheme() to make sure the correct port and scheme are used (the correct ones are in HttpServletRequest, not UriInfo)

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this very issue on my Jersey based application, I used `uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()` to get a `UrlBuilder` and figured out that it's possible to change the hostname from `localhost` by using the `.host()` method

```
.host(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName())
```

And you can remove the port part by setting it to -1

```
.port(-1)
```

So from a URL that looks like

```
https://127.0.0.1:8443/hello
```

I got

```
https://yourhostname/hello
```